# Reference to List Items in Theorem Environment with Label Type “Theorem”

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, enumitem, amsthm

I'm trying to set up references to list items in theorem environments. Using the *thmtools* and the *cref*-package I am able to reference theorem environments, such that the theorem type, e.g. theorem, lemma, corollary, is displayed in the reference (see Exam. 1).

Using the *enumitem*-package I refer to list items in theorem environments, such that the number of the theorem is displayed together with the item number in a reference (see Exam. 2).

Now to my question: Is there an elegant way to combine these two techniques, which would return the theorem type of the environment the list item is in as well as the combination of theorem and item number?
When I'm using the `\autoref{•}` command the label type *item* is displayed (see Exam. 3). Which makes sense since my list environment *thmlist* is derived form the *enumerate* environment. Using `\cref{•}` just produces two question marks (see Exam. 4).

At the moment I assign the type directly to the `\label` command as a optional parameter (see Exam. 5). But this solution requires me to hard code the theorem type plus *TexMaker* won't recognize the labels.

Since I like separating my theorems into parts an elegant solution for this problem would be very handy.

I shall be grateful for any hint or answer.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Input Type and AMS-Packages 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

% Typography
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}), ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti}),noitemsep}

% Math, Operators and Theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Theorem,
    %refname={theorem,theorems},        %Lower Case Versions of Theorem Type
    Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
    numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    %refname={lemma,lemmas},
    Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
    sibling=thm]{lem}

% References
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
\item Statment 2\label[thm]{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
\item Statment 2\label[lem]{thm:B2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}

\begin{description}
\item[1:] That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A} and \cref{thm:B}.
\item[2:] That's how I refer to parts of theorems but without the label type: \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B1}.
\item[3:] This happens when using \verb+\autoref{•}:+ \autoref{thm:A1} and \autoref{thm:B1}.
\item[4:] This happens when using \verb+\cref{•}:+ \cref{thm:A1} and \cref{thm:B1}.
\item[5:] My current work around: \cref{thm:A2} and \cref{thm:B2}.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an attempt based on your example. I used the theorem hooks defined by `thmtools` to override the format for `thmlisti` in the current environment:

```
\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{lem}}
```

I cannot promise that it won't break anything, for example if you use a `thmlist` without any surrounding theorem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Input Type and AMS-Packages 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

% Typography
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}), ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti}),noitemsep}


% Math, Operators and Theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
%refname={theorem,theorems},        %Lower Case Versions of Theorem Type
Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
name=Lemma,
%refname={lemma,lemmas},
Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
sibling=thm]{lem}

% References
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

%%% NEW
\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{lem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
  \begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
    \item Statment 2\label[thm]{thm:A2}
  \end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
  \begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
    \item Statment 2\label[lem]{thm:B2}
  \end{thmlist}
\end{lem}

\begin{description}
  \item[1:] That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A} and \cref{thm:B}.
  \item[2:] That's how I refer to parts of theorems but without the label type: \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B1}.
  \item[3:] This happens when using \verb+\autoref{•}:+ \autoref{thm:A1} and \autoref{thm:B1}.
  \item[4:] This happens when using \verb+\cref{•}:+ \cref{thm:A1} and \cref{thm:B1} (now working)
  \item[5:] My current work around: \cref{thm:A2} and \cref{thm:B2}.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: +1 for accepting the challenge and for the nice solution ;-)

Comment: I am pretty happy with your answer @T.Verron, but could one define the reference type of the `thmlisti`using a command of the `clverref`-package as compared to the `enumitem`-package. Sometimes it would be useful that `\ref{thm:A1}`as in Example 2 returned «(i)»?

Comment: @tim6her : I believe you should ask it as a follow-up question. Note that even without the `\crefalias` tweak, `\ref` and `\autoref` still include the theorem number in the label. That's because this number is included the moment the label is defined, from `ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti})`. I cannot think of any simple way out of this.

Comment: Of course, if you _always_ want the label to be `(i)`, you can simply override this `ref` parameter, either globally or locally. But I understand you want to do this on a per-`\ref` basis, not per-`\label`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution.

Define a new list `lemlist`

```
\newlist{lemlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[lemlist]{label=(\roman{lemlisti}), ref=\thethm.(\roman{lemlisti}),noitemsep}
```

and use this one inside `lem`.

Then, declare

```
\Crefname{thmlisti}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lemlisti}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
```

and you will be able to avoid the optional argument for `\label`s.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Input Type and AMS-Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

% Typography
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}), ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti}),noitemsep}
\newlist{lemlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[lemlist]{label=(\roman{lemlisti}), ref=\thethm.(\roman{lemlisti}),noitemsep}

% Math, Operators and Theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Theorem,
    %refname={theorem,theorems},        %Lower Case Versions of Theorem Type
    Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
    numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    %refname={lemma,lemmas},
    Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
    sibling=thm]{lem}

% References
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{thmlisti}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lemlisti}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
\begin{lemlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{lemlist}
\end{lem}

\begin{description}
\item[1:] That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A} and \cref{thm:B}.
\item[2:] That's how I refer to parts of theorems but without the label type: \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B1}.
\item[3:] This happens when using \verb+\autoref{•}:+ \autoref{thm:A1} and \autoref{thm:B1}.
\item[4:] This happens when using \verb+\cref{•}:+ \cref{thm:A1} and \cref{thm:B1}.
\item[5:] My current work around: \cref{thm:A2} and \cref{thm:B2}.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's only a partial solution, since you still end up hard-coding the theorem type somehow.

Comment: @T.Verron Not a big problem, I think. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: Challenge accepted. `:)` Your approach could probably be mixed with theorem hooks too, and that may be a more robust solution for the whole problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to improve the great answer by @T.Verron such that `\ref` will return the plain counter of the list-environments while `\cref` will return the complete label compromising type, number of theorem and counter of the list (see my comment on @T.Verron's answer).

To do so I set up two new counters

```
\newcounter{listthm}
\newcounter{listlem}
```

whose names correspond to the theorem environment I want to use them in

```
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{listthm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{listlem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
```

In the theorem's *headposthook* the style of `thmlisti`is now set to `listthm`or `listlem`respectively.

```
\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listthm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listlem}}
```

The critical step is that I am now able to tinker with the label format of `listthm`and `listlem`without affecting the format of `thm`and `lem` solely making use of commands provided by the `cref`-package

```
\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}
\creflabelformat{listlem}{#2\thethm.#1#3}
```

Now I can avoid setting the `ref`-style of `thmlisti`using the `enumitem`-package which caused the `\ref`-command to return the counter of the theorem as well.

For full details see my example below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Input Type and AMS-Packages 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

% Typography
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}),noitemsep}

% Math, Operators and Theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Theorem,
    numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    sibling=thm]{lem}

% References
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{listthm}
\newcounter{listlem}


\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{listthm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{listlem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}


\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listthm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listlem}}

\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}
\creflabelformat{listlem}{#2\thethm.#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}


\begin{enumerate}
\item That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A} and \cref{thm:B}.
\item Referring to parts of theorems works like a charm with \verb+\cref{•}:+ \cref{thm:A1} and \cref{thm:B1}.
\item If I use \verb+\ref{•}+ to refer to a part of a theorem \LaTeX{} returns \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B2}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The theorem number when doing `\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}` and `\creflabelformat{listlem}{#2\thethm.#1#3}` is not correct (see item 2 of your screenshot), because it corresponds to the current value of the `thm` counter when `\cref` is called, as opposed to the value this counter had when the label was created. See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499827/73317) for a possible fix.

Answer (score 1):

(**Dependency graph:** this answer improves on [@frougon's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73317/frougon), which improves on [@tim6her's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47065/tim6her), which improves on [@T.Verron's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162905/110223).)

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655032/110223), it is possible to design a slightly more general solution:

- that does not rely on the hooks of `thmtools` and enables you to choose another theorem package,
- that does not need defining specific lists inside theorem, by customizing `enumerate` inside the theorem environments only.

See the linked post for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed version of [tim6her's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207289/73317) . The problem in that answer is that `\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}` doesn't take the `thm` counter from the label, instead it uses the value of the `thm` counter that is current when `\cref` is called. The fix proposed below consists in setting `ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti})` in the `\setlist[thmlist]{...}` command used for theorem “subitems.”

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}),
                  ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti}),
                  noitemsep}

\declaretheorem[
    name=Theorem,
    numberwithin=section]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
    name=Lemma,
    sibling=thm]{lem}

% References
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{listthm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{listlem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listthm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listlem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}

\begin{lem}\label{thm:C}
\begin{thmlist}
\item Statment 1\label{thm:C1}
\item Statment 2\label{thm:C2}
\item Statment 3\label{thm:C3}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}


\begin{enumerate}
\item That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A} and
      \cref{thm:B}.
\item Referring to parts of theorems works like a charm with
      \verb|\cref|: \cref{thm:A1} and \cref{thm:B1}.
\item If I use \verb|\ref| to refer to a part of a theorem, \LaTeX\ prints
      \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B2}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]