# Referencing an in-theorem list item without the preceding theorem number

Tags: cleveref

I am trying to define a variant of `\ref` that picks out only the item number of an in-theorem list item *without* the preceding theorem number. For example:

**Theorem 1.1.**

(i) Something important.

(ii) Something important that refers to (i).

However, I can only manage the following:

**Theorem 1.1.**

(i) Something important.

(ii) Something important that refers to 1.1(i).

Note that I do still want to be able to print the counter 1.1(i), since I may wish to use it later on in the document. That is, in addition to being able to print 1.1(i) and Theorem 1.1(i) using the commands `\ref{theoremlabel}` and `\Cref{theoremlabel}` respectively, I'd like a new command `\itemref{itemlabel}` that prints just (i). I would like all three to be clickable too (using the `hyperref` package).

Note that this is very similar to the question [ref to subsection number only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159299/ref-to-subsection-number-only) and I've tried to adapt the solution givien there by [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel) but alas my TeX coding skills are lacking.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}), ref=\thethm(\roman{thmlisti})}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}

\begin{document}

\section{A theorem}

\begin{thm}\label{theoremlabel}~
\begin{thmlist}

\item\label{itemlabel} Something important.

\item Something important about \ref{itemlabel}. [Here's where I'd like to use my proposed \verb+\itemref{itemlabel}+ command.]

\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

Later on in my document... Isn't \Cref{theoremlabel} interesting? I particularly like its clickable counter \ref{theoremlabel}.

\end{document}
```

Notet: The clever trick using the `\addtotheorempostheadhook` command is due to [T. Verron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9517/t-verron) in the question [Reference to List Items in Theorem Environment with Label Type “Theorem”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162884/reference-to-list-items-in-theorem-environment-with-label-type-theorem).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've an idea with `refcount` in my mind, in conjunction with `xstring`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/relative-chapter-references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\p@<counter>` feature: when the counter's representation, it's preceded by the expansion of `\p@<counter>` (usually empty), which we can use for our purposes, that is inserting in it `\thethm`, but as the argument to another command that we can redefine at point of use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@thmlisti}{\perh@ps{\thethm}}
% the same \DeclareRobustCommand{\perh@ps}[1]{#1}, but more efficient
\protected\def\perh@ps#1{#1}

\newcommand{\itemref}[1]{%
  \begingroup % locally disable \perh@ps
  \let\perh@ps\@gobble\ref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}

\begin{document}

\section{A theorem}

\begin{thm}\label{theoremlabel}\mbox{}
\begin{thmlist}

\item\label{itemlabel} Something important.

\item Something important about \itemref{itemlabel}.

\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

Later on in my document... Isn't \Cref{theoremlabel} interesting? 
I particularly like its clickable counter \ref{theoremlabel}
and \ref{itemlabel}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative solution, that satisfies Barbara Beeton's and my tastes, with upright item markers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=\textup{(\roman{thmlisti})},ref={(\roman{thmlisti})}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@thmlisti}{\perh@ps{\thethm}}
\protected\def\perh@ps#1#2{\textup{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\itemrefperh@ps}[2]{\textup{#2}}
\newcommand{\itemref}[1]{\begingroup\let\perh@ps\itemrefperh@ps\ref{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}

\begin{document}

\section{A theorem}

\begin{thm}\label{theoremlabel}\mbox{}
\begin{thmlist}

\item\label{itemlabel} Something important.

\item Something important about \itemref{itemlabel}.

\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

Later on in my document... Isn't \Cref{theoremlabel} interesting? 
I particularly like its clickable counter \ref{theoremlabel}
and \ref{itemlabel}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Redefined some stuff, hyperlinks works, basically I reinvented the way John Kormylo did it (Please upvotes his answer there too!): 
[How to change the appearance of \ref depending on where it's called relative to the \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to)

I've defined the requested `\itemref`, using the `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package. With `\StrBetween` it's possible to search the item label between the parentheses: `(i)`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label={\textup{(\roman{thmlisti})}}, ref={\textup{\thethm(\roman{thmlisti})}}}


\providecommand{\itemreffont}[1]{\textup{#1}}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{thm}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\itemref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{\refused{#1}}{%
  \edef\tempx{\detokenize\getrefnumber{#1}}%  Fetch the literal reference 1.1(i) (here)
  \StrBetween{\tempx}{(}{)}[\@itemref]%  Get what's between the parantheses
  \edef\restore@@@@link{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
  \hyperlink{\restore@@@@link}{\itemreffont{(\@itemref)}}% Display the reference
  }%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\section{A theorem}

\begin{thm}\label{theoremlabel}~
\begin{thmlist}

\item\label{itemlabel} Something important.

\item Something important about \itemref{itemlabel}. [Here's where I'd like to use my proposed \verb+\itemref{itemlabel}+ command.]

\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

Later on in my document... Isn't \Cref{theoremlabel} interesting? I particularly like its clickable counter \ref{theoremlabel}.

\newpage
Test for the hyperlink: \itemref{itemlabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please make the item labels upright.  it looks so much nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Agreed, it looks nicer -- I've done so, however, it looks strange in conjunction that the list labels are italic nevertheless -- compare *(ii)* and (i)... but, in the end, this is somewhat a matter of taste

Comment: i really meant the list labels too (which is what i usually mean by "item labels).  they *definitely* should have the same style, and the style i'm used to (and preferred by ams) is *always upright*.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, but that's the style of the O.P.

Comment: ah -- i didn't actually process the example.