# Reference to List Items in Theorem Environment

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, theorems, enumitem

I'm trying to implement and customize the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207289/173662) that admits cross-referencing in the theorem environment.

The following attempt is extracted from my thesis template (so some packages might not be used, but they are necessary for me).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,final]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\slshape]{slshape}
\declaretheorem[style=slshape,name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=slshape,name=Lemma,numberlike=thm]{lem}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}),noitemsep}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{listthm}
\newcounter{listlem}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{listthm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{listlem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listthm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listlem}}

\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}
\creflabelformat{listlem}{#2\thethm.#1#3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Peek-a-boo}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:C}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:C1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:C2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:D}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:D1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:D2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{enumerate}
\item That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A}, \cref{thm:B} and \cref{thm:C}.
\item Referring to parts of theorems works like a charm with \verb+\cref{•}:+
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{thm:A1}
        \item \cref{thm:B1}
        \item \cref{thm:C}
        \item \cref{thm:C1}
        \item \cref{thm:C2}
    \end{itemize}
\item If I use \verb+\ref{•}+ to refer to a part of a theorem \LaTeX{} returns \ref{thm:A1} and \ref{thm:B2} and \ref{thm:A}.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

aaa

\end{document}
```

The output is almost perfect.
[image]

All links refer to parts that they are meant to refer, but there is a problem with counters (I guess?). That is, all the following `cref`s

```
\cref{thm:A1}
\cref{thm:B1}
\cref{thm:C1}
\cref{thm:C2}
```

print number of the very last theorem. So the natural question, how/what to fix there, please?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: `\creflabelformat{listthm}{#2\thethm.#1#3}` is simply wrong. \thethm doesn't refer to a labeled value, it will print the *current* value of the thm-counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following (I came to the [same conclusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499815/reference-to-list-items-in-theorem-environment#comment1262421_499815) as Ulrike Fischer: the original code doesn't take the `thm` counter from the label, instead it uses the value of the `thm` counter that is current when `\cref` is called). The theorem number to use in references can be set with `ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti})` in the `\setlist[thmlist]{...}` command related to theorem subitems.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\slshape]{slshape}
\declaretheorem[style=slshape,name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=slshape,name=Lemma,numberlike=thm]{lem}

\newlist{thmlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmlist]{label=(\roman{thmlisti}),
                  ref=\thethm.(\roman{thmlisti}),
                  noitemsep}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{listthm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{listlem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\addtotheorempostheadhook[thm]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listthm}}
\addtotheorempostheadhook[lem]{\crefalias{thmlisti}{listlem}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Peek-a-boo}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{lem}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:C}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:C1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:C2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:D}
Assumptions
\begin{thmlist}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:D1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:D2}
\end{thmlist}
\end{thm}

\begin{enumerate}
\item That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A},
      \cref{thm:B} and \cref{thm:C}.
\item Referring to parts of theorems works like a charm with \verb|\cref|:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{thm:A1}
        \item \cref{thm:B1}
        \item \cref{thm:C}
        \item \cref{thm:C1}
        \item \cref{thm:C2}
    \end{itemize}
\item If I use \verb|\ref| to refer to a part of a theorem, \LaTeX\ prints
     \ref{thm:A1}, \ref{thm:B2} and \ref{thm:A}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @frougon's answer, using:

- the `enumerate` list itself, without defining a `thmlist` (so that one doesn't have to modify all the list environments in theorems),
- `etoolbox` and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` hook instead of the hooks from `thmtools` (so that the solution doesn't rely on a specific theorem package — here I'm using `ntheorem`, and I also tested it with `amsthm`).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\Crefname{thmenumi}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}{%
    \crefalias{enumi}{thmenumi}%
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{
        label={\textit{(\roman*)}},
        ref={\thethm.(\roman*)}
    }%
}

\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{lemenumi}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lem}{%
    \crefalias{enumi}{lemenumi}%
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{
        label={\textit{(\roman*)}},
        ref={\thelem.(\roman*)}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Peek-a-boo}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:A}
Assumptions
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:A1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:A2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{thm:B}
Assumptions
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:B1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:B2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{lem}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:C}
Assumptions
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:C1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:C2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:D}
Assumptions
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Statment 1\label{thm:D1}
    \item Statment 2\label{thm:D2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{item:1}
    That's how I refer to theorems and their like: \cref{thm:A},
    \cref{thm:B} and \cref{thm:C}.
\item Referring to parts of theorems works like a charm with \verb|\cref|:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cref{thm:A1}
        \item \cref{thm:B1}
        \item \cref{thm:C}
        \item \cref{thm:C1}
        \item \cref{thm:C2}
    \end{itemize}
\item If I use \verb|\ref| to refer to a part of a theorem, \LaTeX\ prints
     \ref{thm:A1}, \ref{thm:B2} and \ref{thm:A}.
\item Referring to items outside theorems (like \cref{item:1}) works as usual.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to define the format for theorems and lemmas at once using `\foreach` or similar? I got some errors when I tried to place the definitions inside `\foreach` and wasn't sure how to resolve them.